# Accessing values from a nested JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

This is the `cred.json` file I am trying to parse in my program.

```
{"accounts":[
        {
                "id":"1",
                "username":"user1",
                "password":"password1"
        },
        {
                "id":"2",
                "username":"user2",
                "password":"password2"
        }
]}
```

Here is the code I use for it. This works, but I know it isn't the best way to do it.

```
import json

with open('cred.json') as cred_file:
        parsed_json = json.load(cred_file)
        cred_file.close

        for x in range(0,2):
                user = parsed_json["accounts"][x]["username"]
                password = parsed_json["accounts"][x]["password"]
                print user, ":", password
```

I want to do the same thing, without specifying the range for the loop. When I try to do the same with `iteritems()` or `get()` it is giving me error saying unicode doesn't support those functions.

Please suggest me a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parsed_json` has the entire dict loaded, which contains one key "account" whose value is a list of accounts, as dicts. So instead doing of the range+index lookup, loop over the accounts list directly:

```
for account in parsed_json["accounts"]:
    user = account["username"]
    password = account["password"]
    print user, ":", password
```

Also, you don't need `cred_file.close` (which should be `cred_file.close()` btw) since it closes after you exit the `with` context. The correct way would be:

```
with open('cred.json') as cred_file:
    parsed_json = json.load(cred_file)

for account in parsed_json["accounts"]:
    user = account["username"]
    password = account["password"]
    print user, ":", password
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed noticing that 'accounts' was a list.

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3

```
import json
with open('cred.json') as f:
    lines_read = f.readlines()

json_str = ''.join(lines_read)
json_dict = json.loads(json_str)

for account in json_dict['accounts']:
    user = account['username']
    password = account['password']
    print(user, ':', password)
```

The basic idea is to use python's iterators.